# Do you have to hear the morning blessings of the next minyan before leaving synagogue?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, shacharis-morning-prayer

A minyan has just finished davenning and its participants are leaving.

The next minyan is starting saying the morning blessings.

Is there any obligation of the departing people to hear all the morning blessings before leaving? There could be a reason to stay to be able to answer “omain” to the blessings.

(I ask this because I have observed members of the earlier minyan standing by the exit door while the  morning blessings are being said.)

Comment: Sounds more like a courtesy or getting extra mitzvoth by staying around. Isn't doing this a form of "tircha detzibbur" even though once davening has ended for the earlier minyan, technically, there is no tzibbur?

Comment: I have also seen people who have finished at a previous minyan or who have arrived early for the next minyan, stopping to answer amen just to be able to answer.

Comment: @DanF - In what way are the actions of the first minyan people a "tircha detzibbura"?

Comment: Possibly because people standing in the doorway blocking others prevents others needing to get to work. If there is no need to answer "Amen", why are they blocking others? That deals just spec. with blocking the exit. As for just generally answering "Amen", may not be any case of "tircha", but, I believe that as long as the other minyan has the required # of people to answer "amen (don't recall if it's 6 or 9), why is there any requirement to have any more than that? Lastly, why are you focusing only on Amen to the "morning blessings" - can you specify what you mean by this?

Comment: @DanF - Thank you for explaining. The reason I focus only on Amen to the "morning blessings" because that is the case I observed and wanted help on it.

Comment: It might be a 90 ameins thing

Answer (score 2):

I asked a Rav. He said that there is no obligation to go out of one's way to hear a brocho, especially if it's not one's own minyan. Whenever one does hear a bracha, one should pay attention to its meaning and answer amen. [O Ch 124 (6)](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.124.6?lang=bi).